# JavaScript - add checkbox calculations to total price

Tags: javascript, checkbox, quotes

okay so Im a beginner (a started this journey a day ago) an slowly teaching myself javascript and i wrote a code for a simple price quoter...but now Im trying to build on it.  I know the code is formatted really bad (I have no idea where spaces are supposed to go and those brackets :S) but what i came up with works...does the spacing and stuff matter to the program? or it is for aesthetic reasons and for easy debugging etc...

So my price quote...it has some equations for the total price, time, footage and DVDS...and they are all input fields, and now I want to add check boxes to the equation..if they are checked a value will be added to the total...I have them in the calculator but there is no script attached to them...ONLY THREE check boxes have a set value ...2 check boxes will have a value multiplied by the number of dvds before being added to the total...and the last check box will be another text input similar to what i have already..

ive tried multiple things, like another function but itwas probably done wrong anyways lol, i tried another calculate function, addition function, updatecost function, some chkbox function (i forgot the name)...but I wasnt sure how to get the value calculated in that checkbox's function, into the equation of the calculate function.  i tried the parsefloat thing and it only semi worked if i had the value checked....

another thing i tried was putting an input hidden value of 0 before the value of the input checkbox, both with the same name...some research told me that if the checkbox is not checked, it will default to the hidden value i set with the same name (which is 0)...it didnt work...or i may have no inputed it right in the equation....please direct me in the right direction :) I'm about to pull my hair out!!!

http://jsfiddle.net/yetanothercoder/uFD3y/

```
<html>

<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        .tableheader {
            font-weight: bold;
            font-size: 20px;
            font-family: calibri;
            text-align: center;
        }
        .regreelfont {
            font-size: 15px;
            font-family: calibri;
            text-align: right;
            background-color: #96C6FF;
        }
        .supreelfont {
            font-size: 15px;
            font-family: calibri;
            text-align: right;
            background-color: #7CB8FF;
        }
        .sixreelfont {
            font-size: 15px;
            font-family: calibri;
            text-align: right;
            background-color: #55A1FE;
        }
        .bottomfonts {
            font-family: calibri;
            font-size: 16px;
            font-weight: 900;
        }
        .cellcolor {
            text-align: center;
            background-color: #D2E7FF;
        }
        .cellcolor2 {
            text-align: left;
            background-color: #D2E7FF;
        }
        .rightside {
            background-color: #D2E7FF;
            text-align: right;
        }
        .border {
            border-width: 10px;
            border-radius: 20px;
            border-style: solid;
            border-color: #CBCBCB;
        }
        .leftside {
            text-align: left;
        }
        .bottwo {
            border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
            border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
        }
        .addons {
            font-family: Lucida Console;
            font-size:11px;
            font-weight;
            bold;
        }
        .topleft {
            border-top-left-radius: 10px;
        }
        .topright {
            border-top-right-radius: 10px;
        }
        .orange {
            color: #fef4e9;
            border: solid 1px ##197BFB;
            border-radius: 10px;
            background: #f78d1d;
            background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#197BFB), to(#4A5C75));
            background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #197BFB, #207DF6);
            filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#197BFB', endColorstr='#4A5C75');
        }
        .orange:hover {
            background: #C3D9FF;
        }
        .orange:active {
            color: #000000;
    </style>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        function calculate() {

            var type;

            price = parseFloat(0.20);

            regthree = parseFloat(document.form.regthree.value);
            if (isNaN(regthree)) {
                regthree = 0;
            }
            regfour = parseFloat(document.form.regfour.value);
            if (isNaN(regfour)) {
                regfour = 0;
            }
            regfive = parseFloat(document.form.regfive.value);
            if (isNaN(regfive)) {
                regfive = 0;
            }
            regsix = parseFloat(document.form.regsix.value);
            if (isNaN(regsix)) {
                regsix = 0;
            }
            regseven = parseFloat(document.form.regseven.value);
            if (isNaN(regseven)) {
                regseven = 0;
            }
            supthree = parseFloat(document.form.supthree.value);
            if (isNaN(supthree)) {
                supthree = 0;
            }
            supfour = parseFloat(document.form.supfour.value);
            if (isNaN(supfour)) {
                supfour = 0;
            }
            supfive = parseFloat(document.form.supfive.value);
            if (isNaN(supfive)) {
                supfive = 0;
            }
            supsix = parseFloat(document.form.supsix.value);
            if (isNaN(supsix)) {
                supsix = 0;
            }
            supseven = parseFloat(document.form.supseven.value);
            if (isNaN(supseven)) {
                supseven = 0;
            }
            sixthree = parseFloat(document.form.sixthree.value);
            if (isNaN(sixthree)) {
                sixthree = 0;
            }
            sixfour = parseFloat(document.form.sixfour.value);
            if (isNaN(sixfour)) {
                sixfour = 0;
            }
            sixfive = parseFloat(document.form.sixfive.value);
            if (isNaN(sixfive)) {
                sixfive = 0;
            }
            sixsix = parseFloat(document.form.sixsix.value);
            if (isNaN(sixsix)) {
                sixsix = 0;
            }
            sixseven = parseFloat(document.form.sixseven.value);
            if (isNaN(sixseven)) {
                sixseven = 0;
            }

            regthreetot = parseFloat(regthree * 50);
            regfourtot = parseFloat(regfour * 100);
            regfivetot = parseFloat(regfive * 200);
            regsixtot = parseFloat(regsix * 300);
            regseventot = parseFloat(regseven * 400);
            supthreetot = parseFloat(supthree * 50);
            supfourtot = parseFloat(supfour * 100);
            supfivetot = parseFloat(supfive * 200);
            supsixtot = parseFloat(supsix * 300);
            supseventot = parseFloat(supseven * 400);
            sixthreetot = parseFloat(sixthree * 50);
            sixfourtot = parseFloat(sixfour * 100);
            sixfivetot = parseFloat(sixfive * 200);
            sixsixtot = parseFloat(sixsix * 300);
            sixseventot = parseFloat(sixseven * 400);

            rthreet = parseFloat(regthree * 3.5);
            if (isNaN(regthree)) {
                regthree = 0;
            }
            rfourt = parseFloat(regfour * 7);;
            if (isNaN(regfour)) {
                regfour = 0;
            }
            rfivet = parseFloat(regfive * 14);
            if (isNaN(regfive)) {
                regfive = 0;
            }
            rsixt = parseFloat(regsix * 22);
            if (isNaN(regsix)) {
                regsix = 0;
            }
            rsevent = parseFloat(regseven * 29);
            if (isNaN(regseven)) {
                regseven = 0;
            }
            sthreet = parseFloat(supthree * 3);
            if (isNaN(supthree)) {
                supthree = 0;
            }
            sfourt = parseFloat(supfour * 6);
            if (isNaN(supfour)) {
                supfour = 0;
            }
            sfivet = parseFloat(supfive * 13);
            if (isNaN(supfive)) {
                supfive = 0;
            }
            ssixt = parseFloat(supsix * 20);
            if (isNaN(supsix)) {
                supsix = 0;
            }
            ssevent = parseFloat(supseven * 26);
            if (isNaN(supseven)) {
                supseven = 0;
            }
            sithreet = parseFloat(sixthree * 1.5);
            if (isNaN(sixthree)) {
                sixthree = 0;
            }
            sifourt = parseFloat(sixfour * 3);
            if (isNaN(sixfour)) {
                sixfour = 0;
            }
            sifivet = parseFloat(sixfive * 7);
            if (isNaN(sixfive)) {
                sixfive = 0;
            }
            sisixt = parseFloat(sixsix * 11);
            if (isNaN(sixsix)) {
                sixsix = 0;
            }
            sisevent = parseFloat(sixseven * 14);
            if (isNaN(sixseven)) {
                sixseven = 0;
            }

            totalprice = parseFloat(regthreetot + regfourtot + regfivetot + regsixtot + regseventot + supthreetot + supfourtot + supfivetot + supsixtot + supseventot + sixthreetot + sixfourtot + sixfivetot + sixsixtot + sixseventot) * price;
            tottime = parseFloat(rthreet + rfourt + rfivet + rsixt + rsevent + sthreet + sfourt + sfivet + ssixt + ssevent + sithreet + sifourt + sifivet + sisixt + sisevent)
            totalfoot = parseFloat(regthreetot + regfourtot + regfivetot + regsixtot + regseventot + supthreetot + supfourtot + supfivetot + supsixtot + supseventot + sixthreetot + sixfourtot + sixfivetot + sixsixtot + sixseventot)

            dvdcal = parseFloat(tottime / 60)
            totdvd = Math.ceil(dvdcal)


            document.form.quote.value = totalprice;
            document.form.totalfootage.value = totalfoot;
            document.form.ttime.value = tottime;
            document.form.totdvd.value = totdvd;
            document.form.totad.value = music
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <form name="form">
        <table class="border" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3">
            <tr>
                <td class="tableheader cellcolor topleft">Reel Size</td>
                <td class="tableheader cellcolor topright"># of Reels</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="regreelfont">3" Regular8 (50 ft)</font>
                </td>
                <td class="cellcolor">
                    <input type="text" name="regthree" style="font-family:Verdana; background-color:#FFFFE5; text-align:center; height:30px; width:60px; font-size:21px">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="regreelfont">4" Regular8 (100 ft)</td>
                <td class="cellcolor">
                    <input type="text" name="regfour" style="font-family:Verdana; background-color:#FFFFE5; text-align:center; height:30px; width:60px; font-size:21px">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="regreelfont">5" Regular8 (200 ft)</td>
                <td class="cellcolor">
                    <input type="text" name="regfive" style="font-family:Verdana; background-color:#FFFFE5; text-align:center; height:30px; width:60px; font-size:21px">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="regreelfont">6" Regular8 (300 ft)</td>
                <td class="cellcolor">
                    <input type="text" name="regsix" style="font-family:Verdana; background-color:#FFFFE5; text-align:center; height:30px; width:60px; font-size:21px">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="regreelfont">7" Regular8 (400 ft)</td>
                <td class="cellcolor">
                    <input type="text" name="regseven" style="font-family:Verdana; background-color:#FFFFE5; text-align:center; height:30px; width:60px; font-size:21px">
                </td>
                <tr></tr>
                <td class="supreelfont">3" Super8 (50 ft)</td>
                <td class="cellcolor">
                    <input type="text" name="supthree" style="font-family:Verdana; background-color:#FFFFE5; text-align:center; height:30px; width:60px; font-size:21px">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="supreelfont">4" Super8 (100 ft)</td>
                <td class="cellcolor">
                    <input type="text" name="supfour" style="font-family:Verdana; background-color:#FFFFE5; text-align:center; height:30px; width:60px; font-size:21px">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="supreelfont">5" Super8 (200 ft)</td>
                <td class="cellcolor">
                    <input type="text" name="supfive" style="font-family:Verdana; background-color:#FFFFE5; text-align:center; height:30px; width:60px; font-size:21px">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="supreelfont">6" Super8 (300 ft)</td>
                <td class="cellcolor">
                    <input type="text" name="supsix" style="font-family:Verdana; background-color:#FFFFE5; text-align:center; height:30px; width:60px; font-size:21px">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="supreelfont">7" Super8 (400 ft)</td>
                <td class="cellcolor">
                    <input type="text" name="supseven" style="font-family:Verdana; background-color:#FFFFE5; text-align:center; height:30px; width:60px; font-size:21px">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="sixreelfont">3" 16mm (50 ft)</td>
                <td class="cellcolor">
                    <input type="text" name="sixthree" style="font-family:Verdana; background-color:#FFFFE5; text-align:center; height:30px; width:60px; font-size:21px">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td td class="sixreelfont">4" 16mm (100 ft)</td>
                <td class="cellcolor">
                    <input type="text" name="sixfour" style="font-family:Verdana; background-color:#FFFFE5; text-align:center; height:30px; width:60px; font-size:21px">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td td class="sixreelfont">5" 16mm (200 ft)</td>
                <td class="cellcolor">
                    <input type="text" name="sixfive" style="font-family:Verdana; background-color:#FFFFE5; text-align:center; height:30px; width:60px; font-size:21px">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td td class="sixreelfont">6" 16mm (300 ft)</td>
                <td class="cellcolor">
                    <input type="text" name="sixsix" style="font-family:Verdana; background-color:#FFFFE5; text-align:center; height:30px; width:60px; font-size:21px">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td td class="sixreelfont">7" 16mm (400 ft)</td>
                <td class="cellcolor">
                    <input type="text" name="sixseven" style="font-family:Verdana; background-color:#FFFFE5; text-align:center; height:30px; width:60px; font-size:21px">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="cellcolor addons leftside" colspan="2">BACKGROUND MUSIC - $14.99
                    <input type="checkbox" name="ckBox" id="ckBox">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="cellcolor addons leftside" colspan="2">TITLES (PER DVD) - $9.99
                    <input type="checkbox" name="titles">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="cellcolor addons leftside" colspan="2">TRANSITIONS (PER DVD) - $9.99
                    <input type="checkbox" name="transitions"
                    </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="cellcolor addons leftside" colspan="2">FILM REPAIR AND SPLICING - $14.99
                    <input type="checkbox" name="adees" value="14.99">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="cellcolor addons leftside" colspan="2">SPECIAL FILM EDITING - $100.00
                    <input type="checkbox" name="adees" value="100">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="cellcolor addons leftside" colspan="2">EXTRA COPIES - $9.99 PER COPY
                    <input type="text" name="copies" style="font-family:Verdana; background-color:#FFFFE5; text-align:center; height:25px; width:50px; font-size:15px">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="cellcolor" colspan="2"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="rightside bottomfonts" colspan="2">TOTAL PRICE ($)
                    <input type="text" name="quote" style="font-family:Verdana; background-color:#FFFFE5; height:25px; text-align:center; width:100px; font-size:16px">
                </td>
                <tr/>
                <tr>
                    <td class="rightside bottomfonts" colspan="2">FOOTAGE (ft)
                        <input type="text" name="totalfootage" size="7" style="font-family:Verdana; background-color:#FFFFE5; text-align:center; height:25px; width:100px; font-size:16px"
                        </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="rightside bottomfonts" colspan="2">TOTAL TIME (min)
                        <input type="text" name="ttime" size="7" style="font-family:Verdana; background-color:#FFFFE5; text-align:center; height:25px; width:100px; font-size:16px">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="rightside bottomfonts" colspan="2">TOTAL DVDs
                        <input type="text" name="totdvd" size="7" style="font-family:Verdana; background-color:#FFFFE5; text-align:center; height:25px; width:100px; font-size:16px">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="cellcolor bottwo" colspan="2">
                        <input type="button" class="orange" style="font-size: 18px; width:60px;height:35px"
                        value="Clear" onClick="this.form.reset()">&nbsp
                        <input type="button" name="Button" class="orange" style="font-size: 18px; width:120px;height:35px"
                        value="Calculate" onClick="calculate()">
                    </td>
                </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: start using [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) to share your code

Comment: cool! thats much better to look at hahaha thanks :)

Comment: I'm assuming that, by suggestions, you mean relating to your code (if not I think your 'price per extra copy' is a little high for a DVD rip), but otherwise I'd suggest using class-names to identify the relevant inputs, and, perhaps a custom `data-*` attribute to identify the price, but I've not really explored it fully). Incidentally when working out the 'transitions (per DVD)' cost, do the 'extra copies serve to multiply that cost, or is it just the number of DVDs submitted?

Comment: lol yah the prices are not final yet..i just want to get this going but your right haha ;) it is pretty high but im going to change it later...you can make classes in javascript? what about ids?

the transitions per dvd will be based on the total dvds input...output lol (which is the total time in minutes divided but 60 and rounded up)

Comment: I think you're going to need to ask a more focused question to get answers. I'd suggest you remove the personal background, make the question very brief, and give formatted code examples (indent four spaces) for exactly what you've tried. The more your question is likely to come up on a web search and help someone else, the better it is.

Comment: Also, some advice: ruthlessly apply the **DRY** (Don't Repeat Yourself) principle to this code. For instance, all your identical `style=` tags should be replaced with rules for CSS classes. Each input should have all the data you need for it encoded in its attributes, perhaps with a `data` attribute. You should have a single function that loops through all the inputs and does all the calculations, so you could add another product without changing the JS at all. Less repetition means fewer places to fix something later. This is **crucial** for you to learn to survive in coding.